# Issue returning JSON format PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

currently i'm building my own MVC to try and get a better understanding of the underlying principles of existing frameworks. However i've run into an issue with an AJAX get method i have and trying to output returned data into JSON. Here's the PHP and Javascript below:

```
public function ajaxGet(){
    $stat = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data");
    $stat->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //fetch the data as an associative array
    $stat->execute();
    $data = $stat->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($data);
    //since we are passing the data from a json encoded ajax request
    //we must format it that way here
}
```

And below is my javascript.

```
$(function(){

$.get("/mvc2/dashboard/ajaxGet", function(o){

    console.log(o); //for some reason i had to remove 'json' to get this to work??
    for(var i=0;i<1;i++){

        $('#listInserts').append('<div>'+o+'</div><br>');
    }

    }, 'json'); 
    //output in json format


$('#accountInsert').submit(function(){

    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    //this gets the value of action in our form
    //so we can pass all the data and hadle the request from there 
    var data = $(this).serialize(); 
    //The serialize() method creates a URL encoded text string by serializing form values.
    $.post(url, data, function(o){
        //post the url and the data
        //and have a call back function called 'o'
        console.log(url, data);
    });

    return false; 
    //return flase so the form data can be handled
    //through javascript
    //and so we don't refresh the page
});
```

});

Now please note, that when i remove the 'json' tag from my javascript function, the data is output an an associate array, and even with the tag there i can see that the data is returned in the function response from chrome. But no data is logged or alerted.

Comment: Before echoing the json string, try to send a header like that: `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: Show the result of your `console.log(o);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

PHP:

```
public function ajaxGet(){
    $stat = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data");
    $stat->execute();
    $data = $stat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data);
    //since we are passing the data from a json encoded ajax request
    //we must format it that way here
}
```

JS:

1. Be sure to comment out any `console.log` methods if you're not using the console
2. In your callback for AJAX calls, check the console.log. Your `o` is the OBJECT of data returned.. with that said, you'll need to access the properties with something like `o.colName` from your PHP result.
3. Ensure your MVC path is correct, I believe you said it is because you saw an array of sort.

Comment: Hi, still no luck i'm afraid. But yes i know what you mean. I'm passing the o on it's own and logging it because i want to see all the returned data as an object. But it's not logging anything. Defining it with say o[0].id returns nowt. The path is correct, i can see the returned data in my network resources in Chrome. Here's a picture of what i mean: [Image](http://broconut.com/i/507e7f0b37270.png)

Comment: That array is not coming from `json_encode` - it's rogue and it's breaking your script.

Comment: After you figure out where you stuck the `print_r` call, comment it out and test again. In your JS, you can then iterate through your results with `$.each(o, function(i, v) { console.log(v.id, v.data); });`

Comment: So that's likely the problem, how would i go about fixing it?

Comment: That did the job Rob, thank you very much! I had the print_r() in my main init() call. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Either you provide proper HTTP headers in your response:

```
...
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

or you use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()`.

Comment: No luck with either or both i'm afraid :/ . Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: You don't need the content type, it's just good practice. His third parameter in $.get is 'json' - which specifies to automatically parse the json.